# Why can't we use "to" after tell?

Tags: usage

> I said *to* him.
>   I told him.

Why can't we use *to* after *tell*, when we are using *to* after *say*?

Comment: Note that it's almost impossible to come up with a context where your first "sentence" would be valid, but the second one could be a perfectly normal response to, for example, *"Does John know we're supposed to be meeting in the bar before the concert starts?"*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's mostly just an idiomatic tendency that we normally include *to* after *say*, but not after *tell*. But note that the basic syntax of something like...

> [I told the truth to you](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22crawling%20out%20of%20the%20woodwork%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22told%20the%20truth%20to%20you%22&oq=%22told%20the%20truth%20to%20you%22&gs_l=serp.3...58421.65468.1.65946.30.30.0.0.0.1.124.1698.27j3.30.0...0.0...1c.1.7.psy-ab.ES60XkK9QEc&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44442042,d.d2k&fp=93f637ceeafc3c9d&biw=1262&bih=866)

...is perfectly okay (if dated), and there's nothing "ungrammatical" about those 1410 written instances.

If OP really wants an "explanation" for the tendency, I'd suggest it's because although both *to say* and *to tell* normally require at least one "indirect object" (the thing said), *to tell* normally requires a second indirect object (who it was told to).

You can quite reasonably *say* or *tell something **to** someone*, but you can't normally just *tell something*, without saying *who you're telling it to*. Syntactically, the verb *to tell* is more strongly associated with *the person being told*.

That's to say, it's inherent in the meaning of the verb *to tell* that there must be a listener (whereas you can *say* something even if nobody hears it). Thus we don't need a preposition to clarify the relationship between speaker and listener with *to tell*; over time we've gradually tended to discard it as unnecessary.

---

Note: *to tell* is a [ditransitive verb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ditransitive_verb). It takes a subject (the person doing the telling) and *two* objects (the person told, and *what* was told). In that (default) order, no preposition is necessary or normal...

> I told you a lie
>   Tell me a story *(imperative: implied subject "You" in front)*

Sometimes you can put "the person told" *after* "what was told", but *then you need the "to" preposition...*

> I told a lie **to** you
>    ?Tell a story **to** me

The '?' before that last one indicates that not all native speakers would find it very natural today. Such constructions were more acceptable in the past, probably before the modern-day prepositionless default sequence became established.

It's not really worth "learning" how to use *tell something **to** someone* - just be prepared to accept it if you encounter it, but use *tell someone something* yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot really answer the *why* part of your question. That's the way we speak and that's how languages are. Certain parts of any language, including English, have more an *idiomatic* rather than *grammatical* touch to them. And this is one of them. Usually the rule is to use *tell* with a personal object and *say* without a personal object. So,

> You say something
>
> You tell someone something