# Verb + Preposition (how to learn)

Tags: prepositions, verbs

I have been learning English recently, but I have problems with learning English verbs and prepositions. I know how some verbs work.

1. I **let** you do it
2. I **allow** you **to** do it
3. I **said to** you a week ago
4. I **told** you a week ago

However, I want to improve my oral skills and verbs are most important for it. Please, give me some advise. How can I learn about "verb + preposition" combinations?

Comment: As John's answer says, there are many different phenomena in these sentences. The specific issue of "why" you *say something **to** someone*, but you *tell them* with no preposition, is covered in more detail [on this earlier question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/4824/why-cant-we-use-to-after-tell/4825#4825). But I don't know whether it will help with other verbs, and it certainly won't explain why *let* takes an unmarked infinitive complement, whereas *allow* requires an marked infinitive.

Answer (score 5):

There are many different phenomena in the sentences you list.
Most of them don't really have much to do with prepositions in general, but with specific constructions.

1. *I let you do it* is a complex sentence with an **unmarked** infinitive complement.
2. *I allow you to do it* is a complex sentence with a **marked** infinitive complement.
3. *I said `X` to you a week ago* is a simple sentence with a direct object `X` and an indirect object *you*.  The verb *say* does **not** allow the Dative Alternation.
4. *I told you `X` a week ago* is the same structure, with the same objects.
   But the verb *tell* does allow the Dative Alternation, and this is the alternate version.
   The unalternated version, *I told `X` to you a week ago*, is also correct.

The "mark" in both cases 1 and 2 is the infinitive complementizer *to*.
This is **not** a preposition and does not behave like one.
For one thing, certain verbs (like *let*) allow one to delete *to* before infinitive complements,
while most verbs, like *allow*, require a *to* to mark infinitives.

In cases 3 and 4, the *to* is part of a bitransitive (transfer) verb 
 -- one that has two objects.
The indirect object in such a sentence can usually be marked with *to*, if it follows the direct object.
However, if it **precedes** the direct object (the Dative Alternation), then *to* is not allowed.

Comment: I might add that I'm unable, as usual, to log in to this site, because it wants me to change my password and doesn't recognize any of my alter egos in ELU.SE or Ling.SE. So I can't make comments except on answers I post. As a guest, natch.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the stack exchange team directly to try and get a resolution to this?

Comment: I have no idea which team that is, nor how to contact them; I'm not a S.E person, just a linguist. There has always been something weird about my S.E logins, and I've had to have somebody fix it up several times. By now gods alone know what shape it's in. And who and how to fix it.

Comment: Ah, I just tried it and the password that I use does not meet the security standard. Since I don't want to set and remember yet another S.E password, I'll just have to pass this time.

Comment: And, of course, since I must log in to post (though not to comment), I can't post in meta about tags, so I'll just link it [here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Tagspost.txt) instead.

Comment: You can always try changing your password here: http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/lost-password or getting other help here http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/lost-password. If you need more help try this: http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/other.

Comment: The problem is that, since the password I use for my other SE personae doesn't meet the ELL standards, and I don't really want, as I said, to set and remember yet another password for ELL, changing my pw won't really help.

Comment: Moderators don't have control over the password policy for StackExchange, or the ability to reset accounts. You need to have this discussion with StackExchange directly via one of those links. Otherwise I really can't help you.